# Вывод дочерней категории в Похожие товары Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Сайт на WP + Woocommerce. На сайте ряд дочерних категорий товаров объеденены родительской. Необходимо чтобы в поле "Похожие товары" выводились только товары данной дочерней категории, исключив при этом родительские. Подскажите возможно ли это дописав в function.php или посредством плагина. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение посредством плагина - Woo Related Products
Но мне кажется лучше будет пара строк кода в function.php нежели ставить целый плагин ради этого.